# Is it possible to undefine a variable in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

In the freemarker template language, I can test whether a variable exists by using constructs like `variable?exists` or `variable??`. I can also cause a previously non-existent variable to exist by assigning to it, e.g., `<#assign variable = "hi" />`. But how can I cause a previously existing variable to no longer exist?

I have some other dude's freemarker template, with logic at various points that tests for the (non-)existence of certain variables. In my use case, it would be simplest if I could have a variable that exists at one point, then becomes undefined when including his template, then gets assigned to again later on. The alternative is to restructure things more significantly.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no directive fort that. Maybe it can be achieved with a custom directive (`TemplateDirectiveModel`) that can then write `null` into the variable through the `Environment`. (Unless the `Environment` API checks for `null`-s...)